# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

`spark version 2.1.1`
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$
        at org.example.sparktest$.main(sparktest.scala:7)
        at org.example.sparktest.main(sparktest.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 2 more

Comment: Check if the **SPARK_HOME** is set in the environment variables of the environment you are using.

Answer (score -1):

SparkSession class is not found at runtime. Try checking the runtime of the environment. If you are trying to run it on Hadoop cluster then check if you are running the code in proper directory.